# Trying to Run two functions and two different emails in google scripts

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, comparison-operators

I'm trying to have my sheet trigger an email alert when the last row on certain column matches an if statement after a google form feeds the sheet. it worked the first time but when i try to do a second condition it only acomplishes the second if. so separated the ifs work, but not combined.

can you guys help? here is the function:

```
function sendEmails() {
  
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Observaciones Diarias IMPRG");
  var lr  = ss.getLastRow();
  
  var currentTemp = ss.getRange(lr, 6).getValue();
  var currentkidName = ss.getRange(lr, 3).getValue();
  var currentTexture = ss.getRange(lr, 15).getValue();
  
  if(currentTemp >39) {
  
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxx25@gmail.com","Temperature>39°Alert", currentkidName + " had atemperature of " + currentTemp + "° " +" which is extremely high, please check")
  }
  
  else if (currentTexture = 1){
    MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com","Texture Alert", currentkidName + " had a  " + " liquid Evacuation. which indicates an issue, please check")
  }
}
```

Comment: Put this in the else if condition `currentTexture == 1`

Comment: it doesn't work anymore, not sure what I did, will it affect that the datasource comes from a sheet that is fed by importrange?

Comment: could be.. share a sample copy of your sheet or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

`currentTexture = 1` this is asigning a 1 to `currentTexture`. To do a comparison use

```
currentTexture == 1
```

or

```
currentTexture === 1
```

Related

- [Google Script checking that the data within one column on one sheet is the same as another column in another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47812317/1595451)
- [How do I find the cell with a certain background color, and set background of different cell in relation to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47877323/1595451)
- [How to set a variable based on other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49590632/1595451)
- [I'm trying to make an id searcher which does a thing when you input the right id. However, the if statement always runs. Why is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50671456/1595451)

Comment: would creating a new spreadsheet and do importrange and make the second script part as a separate one work better?